# Emacs caps lock minor mode?

Tags: emacs, capslock

Is there a command in Emacs to turn on what might be described as "caps lock minor mode"?  I'm looking to do something like `M-x toggle-caps-mode`, then every letter I type in the buffer is a capital letter until I do `M-x toggle-caps-mode` again.

Note:  I'm NOT looking for directions on how to swap caps and control.  In reality this is because I have already done that.  I am generally quite happy with it, but occasionally I'm editing code where there are a bunch of constants that are in all caps, and it gets to be a strain holding down the shift key.  I'm aware of the various `upcase` conversion functions; I'd rather not have to type the word, select it, then run `upcase-region`.

If it matters, I'm using Aquamacs 2.2 w/ Emacs 23.3.1.

Comment: If yow have swapped caps and control then you have caps lock on the control key, don't you? Why don't you use that?

Comment: I guess I'm playing fast and loose with the word "swapped".  I really mean that I've remapped caps to control.  Control is still control, but I could actually swap them.  Still curious if there's a simple answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to type the word then select it. If you want to upcase the last word, press `M-b M-u` or `ESC b u`. Ok, you'll need to press `b` several times if it's a `word_with_underscores`.

If you really want a caps lock minor mode, try [John Paul Wallington's `lockcaps.el`](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gnu-emacs-sources/2001-09/msg00014.html).

Comment: It's a whole bunch of `word_with_underscores`s I'm working with!  lockcaps.el looks promising, though.

Comment: @dantswain You only need to type them once anyway. Then you just type the first few letters and use completion (semantic with `M-TAB` or dynamic with `M-/`).

Comment: Autocomplete's just never been my style, but `lockcaps.el` did just want I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
(define-minor-mode caps-lock-mode
  "caps-lock mode"
  ;;   The initial value.   
  nil   
  ;; The indicator for the mode line.   
  " CAPS-LOCK"   
  ;; The minor mode bindings.   
  '(("a" . (lambda () (interactive) (insert-char ?A 1)))
    ("b" . (lambda () (interactive) (insert-char ?B 1)))
    ;;etc 
    ("A" . (lambda () (interactive) (insert-char ?a 1)))    
    ("B" . (lambda () (interactive) (insert-char ?b 1)))    
    ;;etc
    ))
```

Comment: I found this:  http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gnu-emacs-sources/2004-08/msg00013.html and the various replies, which end up giving a slightly more compact version.  I was hoping for a built-in, but if this is the answer, then this is the answer.  I'll give it some time to see if anyone else has anything different to offer.

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting thread. Especially about how to replace the long keymap with a single function.